# for loop on different variables names

Tags: c

I am programing for a while but for this i couldn't find an answer yet .

lets say i want to run on a loop when i change the names of the variables.

lets say i have :

```
int ran1;
int ran2;
int ran3;
```

now i want to run a for loop that put numbers to them :

```
for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
 ran%k=k; // this is wrong ,but i am looking for the correct way .
          //output should be :ran1=0 ran2=1 ran3=2..
```

i know other ways that takes more lines of code .

Comment: Why won't you use an array instead of set of variables?

Comment: Use array. e.g. `int ran[3]`

Comment: Is using an array not an option?

Comment: You have to understand that unlike in scripting languages in C variable names are compile-time symbols. They do not exist at runtime. It comes with far more speed, but with obvious disadvantages that you can't have dynamic hash tables like the one you are trying to achieve. Arrays is the way to go here if your index is continuos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it an array! Using different names differentiated by a number is a bad practice:

```
int ran[3];

for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
{
    ran[k % 3] = k;
}
```

Now, instead of using `ran1`, or `ran2`, you would use `ran[1]` or `ran[2]`. 
Arrays in C are quite confusing, and they are distinct from pointers.

Comment: @Rant in case you want `k` to be bigger than `2`, it will not break.

Answer (score 5):

If you absolutely have to keep these variables separate, then the only option you have is to "index" your variables by using an array of pointers and access your variables through it

```
int ran1, ran2, ran3;

int *rans[3] = { &ran1, &ran2, &ran3 };

for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
  *rans[k] = k;
```

(But maybe you should have used an `int` array instead of three separate variables from the very beginning.)

Answer (score 1):

uses arrays:

```
int ran[3];
for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
 ran[k]=k;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple achieve this with defining an array as `int ran[3]` and then writing below code to get it:-

```
ran[k % 3] = k;
```